# Generate random number (salaries) based on job titles in Python

Tags: python, numpy, random

Is there any way to generate random numbers (salaries) based on the job title. For example applying weights based in job title. Currently I am doing the following

```
import numpy as np 
from random import randint

job_titles = ['developer','business manager','staff','senior developer']
title = np.random.choice(office_titles, 1, p=[0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1])[0]
if title == 'developer': salary = randint(40000,55000)
elif title == 'business manager': salary = randint(70000,85000)
elif title == 'staff': salary = randint(25000,45000)
else: salary = randint(55000,75000)
```

In my case I have almost 30 job titles and it is not a good way of solving this issue. Can any some guide me what is the efficient way of doing this ?

Comment: You could use a dictionary `{'developer': (40000, 55000), ...}` to simplify a bit.

Comment: Why are you using `randint` when you can use `np.random.randint`? Make a single call for 30 random numbers, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient way of doing this. This solution follows [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s hint and takes into account [COLDSPEED](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%e1%b4%8f%ca%9f%e1%b4%85s%e1%b4%98%e1%b4%87%e1%b4%87%e1%b4%85)'s remark (see comments).

```
import numpy as np

jobs = {
    # 'title': (p, min salary, max salary)
    'developer': (0.4, 40000, 55000),
    'business manager': (0.1, 70000, 85000),
    'staff': (0.4, 25000, 45000),
    'senior developer': (0.1, 55000, 75000),
}

titles = [title for title in jobs.keys()]
p = [job[0] for job in jobs.values()]
title = np.random.choice(titles, size=1, p=p)[0]

min_salary = jobs[title][1]
max_salary = jobs[title][2]
salary = np.random.randint(min_salary, max_salary)
```

Since you have almost 30 job titles, now you only have to complete the `jobs` dictionary. This is probably a better way of solving your issue.

If you really want to apply weights based on job titles then just define salaries in k$ instead of $. Something like this:

```
# ...
jobs = {
    # 'title': (p, min salary, max salary)
    'developer': (0.4, 40, 55),
    'business manager': (0.1, 70, 85),
    'staff': (0.4, 25, 45),
    'senior developer': (0.1, 55, 75),
}
# ...
min_salary = jobs[title][1] * 1000
max_salary = jobs[title][2] * 1000
# ...
```

I hope this will help you.